# Calculating predictions for multiple linear regression

Tags: r, statistics, prediction

I have data about insurance; age, sex, BMI, children, smoker, region and charges. Sex, smoker and region are factors. sex: male, female, smoker: yes, no, region: northeast, southeast, southwest, northwest.

```
m2 <- lm(charges ~ age + sex + bmi + children + smoker + region)
```

After fitting linear regression model with data I need to predict: male, age=40, bmi=30, smoker=yes, region=northwest.
I have tried to factor categorical variables after reading the data

```
data$sex <- as.factor(data$sex)
data$region <- as.factor(data$region)
```

Using the predict function:

```
predict(m2, list(age=40, sex=factor(male), bmi=30, children=2, smoker=factor(yes), 
                 region=factor(northwest)), int="p", level=0.98)
```

I only get errors. Please help

Comment: 1) do the factor levers in the new data match the levels in the old data? in your sample, e.g. the `smoker` variable will only have one level (`yes`) 2) try passing the new data as a data.frame not a list

Comment: also when you pass new data, strings need to be quoted. `smoker=factor(yes)` will look for an object called `yes`. perhaps you mean something like `smoker = factor('yes', levels = c('yes', 'no'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redefining the factors, just use the factor level in quotation marks in `predict`.

```
predict(m2, list(age=40, sex="male", bmi=30, children=2, smoker="yes", 
                 region="northwest"), int="p", level=0.98)
#         fit       lwr      upr
# 1 -1.978994 -9.368242 5.410254
```

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(charges = c(1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, 
0.363128411337339, 0.63286260496104, 0.404268323140999, -0.106124516091484, 
1.51152199743894, -0.0946590384130976, 2.01842371387704, -0.062714099052421
), age = c(20L, 58L, 44L, 53L, 22L, 51L, 20L, 75L, 59L, 41L), 
    sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", 
    "male"), class = "factor"), bmi = c(25.3024309248682, 24.6058854935878, 
    25.7881406228236, 25.6707038267505, 24.0508191903124, 25.036135738485, 
    27.115755613237, 25.1674409043556, 24.1201634714689, 25.9469131749433
    ), children = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L), 
    smoker = c("no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", 
    "yes", "yes", "no"), region = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("northeast", "northwest", 
    "southeast"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```